# update control inside update panel in client side

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

how to update a control inside update panel without reloading(postpack) the update panel please give an example code with C# if you could. so the update should happen in client side.

Thank you,

Comment: -1 Please provide more details in your question and provide any code samples where relevant.

Comment: I'm asking about an idea and if there is an example in the net to implement this idea and now there are 2 programmers understand my question and gave me good feedback.
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, the whole purpose of an UpdatePanel and AJAX in general is a partial post back of the page. If you want to work with something client-side, Javascript is usually the best thing.

Answer (score 0):

If the control is inside an update panel, all you need to do is do all of your postbacks inside that update panel.  So if you have a button event or any server side event that is executed inside the update panel, any control within the update panel will update without a postback

Answer (score 0):

Update panels are tricky and does many things that you cant handle. I recommend an javascript framework with ajax postbacks

Answer (score 0):

You can see the answer of the following question [How to configure UpdatePanel so that it should render empty first time and later after page render refreshes and get data asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602148/how-to-configure-updatepanel-so-that-it-should-render-empty-first-time-and-later/8603903#8603903) , this refreshes update panel from javascript